# Starting screen sessions and running commands in it

Tags: bash, gnu-screen

I'm trying to write a bash script that should be capable of starting a java application in a separate screen. (detached terminal)

what I want to achieve:

- Start a named Screen session
- Run a java command in it
- The session should not be attached

The java command I want to run is a jar application. This application will be running until it is manually stopped, that's why I want the screen to be detached.

Comment: We encourage questioners to show what they have tried so far to solve the problem themselves.

Comment: Is `screen` a requirement, or is any solution detaching the session (like `nohup`) ok?